# How to get customer id from an order not yet paid in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using this code to get the customer_id:

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$customer_id = $order->get_customer_id();
```

I get the `$order` by `woocommerce_new_order` hook.

After that call, `$customer_id` is 0.

If I `var_dump` `$order` I can see the full object, including billing address, but customer id is 0.

That happen when the new order is created, before payment. I can use the e-mail to get the customer, but I am wondering if there is a way to get the custoemr id before order payment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` action instead (`$order_id` is the first argument of that action).

This action is run **before the payment** is being processed and it works for both existing customers, and customers that signed up during the checkout. See the [source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L1171) of `class-wc-checkout.php`:

```
// line 1171
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', $order_id, $posted_data, $order );
// ...
// line 1182
if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_payment', $order->needs_payment(), WC()->cart ) ) {
    $this->process_order_payment( $order_id, $posted_data['payment_method'] );
} else {
    $this->process_order_without_payment( $order_id );
}
```

**Note**: if registration is not required for your customers, the `get_customer_id()` might still throw an error for guest checkouts (because this function always returns an integer). You might want to wrap your code to `if($order->get_user()){}`, because this function returns `false` for guest checkouts.